# How to update multiple users with different value in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose

I have two users. test1 and test2. I need to update language for that users in single query.
Now i am looping them

```
db.collection.update({name : test1}, {lang: node})

db.collection.update({name : test2}, {lang: php})
```

But i don't want that, how can i do that in single query?
is there any way like

```
db.collection.update({[{name: test1}, {lang: node}], [{name : test2}, {lang: php}]}, {multi:true})
```

or

```
 if (name: test1){update lang: node} elseif (name: test2){update lang :  php}
```

sample document

```
{ 
_id: 231123,
name : test1,
lang : java
}
```

Comment: Please add the sample document to the post.

Comment: i think it is not important, still i had done changes in post

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Bulk` API: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/

Normal update API doesn't provide what you want since the query for the update operations are not the same. Bulk is the only API that comes to mind for your use case.